# How to access a URL filtered only for my public IP from outside my network

Tags: iptables

There is this URL which I can access from inside my network, because they allowed my public IP to access it. All other IPs are denied.

how can I configure my iptables so that I can access this website from outside my network?

Answer (score 0):

SSH into a host inside of your network, and then hit the URL with `curl`:

```
ssh user@myhost.example.com 'curl http://othersite.example.com/special/snowflake'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a task for `iptables`.

Use the SOCKS proxy feature of SSH, i.e. do `ssh -L 24680:<remote ip>:80 host.in.your.network`, then you can access the url on `host.in.your.network:24680`,

Comment: Henrik, thanks for your answer. Can you clarify what is "remote ip". Also host.in.your.network should be my public IP?

Comment: `<remote ip>` is the ip of the url that you want to access. `host.in.your.network` can be any ip you can reach the host in your network you want to use on, that is most likely your public ip, but there are other possibilites, if you e.g. have vpn access to your network that might give you another useable ip. - And note that doing this makes that url accesible to anyone able to connect to `host.in.your.network:24680`.

Comment: the website i want to reach is https://190.104.0.109:8116/login. I executed the following ssh line: ssh -L 9999:190.104.0.109:8116 localhost. This is in server 192.168.1.1. Then I open my browser on 192.168.1.122 machine and it says the server rejected the connection

Comment: is it possible to make it work at all?

Comment: It should be possible, but it has been a few years since I used it myself, so I might have mixed the `-L`/`-R` option to `ssh`. I have also confused SOCKS proxying (done with `-D` to ssh and requires some browser configuration) and `-L`/`-R`.

Answer (score -1):

At first you need to encapsulate your traffic to your filtering system doesn't find your content and URL. For do this, You need to choice one of the following ways:

- Use a tunnel via ssh
- Use a VPN
- Use some http tunneling such as zebedee
- Use some tunnel such as ipip or GRE
- Use an "Onion Routing" such as Tor

**NOTE:** You have to have a server outside of your filtering.

I think if you don't have any server , You can use Tor.

**NOTE:** If you want to use in shell , You have to use some bash variable such as : `$http_proxy` and `$SOCKS_PROXY`